# pyqt QThread and Signal and Emit not working for this answer

Tags: python, pyqt

So I've been looking around for an answer for how to use QThreads and Signals, and came across an answer from:

[How to access GUI elements from another thread in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919472/how-to-access-gui-elements-from-another-thread-in-pyqt?rq=1)

And wondering if that's not working for anyone else? The window just freezes. Is  there anything wrong with my computer or is it the answer?

The code is:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as gui
from PyQt4 import QtCore as core

import sys
import time


class ServerThread(core.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        core.QThread.__init__(self)

    def start_server(self):
        for i in range(1,6):
            time.sleep(1)
            self.emit(core.SIGNAL("dosomething(QString)"), str(i))

    def run(self):
        self.start_server()


class MainApp(gui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp,self).__init__(parent)

        self.label = gui.QLabel("hello world!!")

        layout = gui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.thread = ServerThread()
        self.thread.start()

        self.connect(self.thread, core.SIGNAL("dosomething(QString)"), self.doing)

    def doing(self, i):
        self.label.setText(i)
        if i == "5":
            self.destroy(self, destroyWindow =True, destroySubWindows = True)
            sys.exit()


app = gui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainApp()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

That code works for me `Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`. There is one little bug in that snippet though:

You should change this line `self.destroy(self, destroyWindow =True, destroySubWindows = True)` by this `self.destroy(destroyWindow =True, destroySubWindows = True)` otherwise you'll get this error

> TypeError: QWidget.destroy(bool destroyWindow=True, bool destroySubWindows=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'MainApp'